# Purpose of Android Support Library

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am getting started with Android. I am quite confused with what support library actually does . I am following a book and in the book it is mentioned that :

> If an app is installed on a minimum SDK system, and our Java code
>   contains any calls to classes that are not present in minimum SDK ,
>   our app will crash

I read an article about support libraries here:
[Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_support_library)

If Support libraries provide backward compatibility, doesn't it mean when they should prevent app crash?(may be by wrapping up those newer classes and making them backward compatible). What does support library actually do? Please explain.

Comment: Typically they provide an alternative APIs, for example you can get colors using `ContextCompat.getColor(this, id)`, set tint using `app:tint`, or drawables using `app:srcCompat`.

Comment: @AjahnCharles so when a new API(say API 29) is released with some set of new features,  equivalent classes are also developed in older API(say API 22) and added in support libraries? Am I correct?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library for details.

Comment: @srinivas chaitanya - Yes, possibly a full "polyfill", possibly just a limited or null implementation (emulating some of the functionality or at least not crashing).

Answer (score 1):

**When should I use the Android Support Library?**

As new versions of Android are released, some style and behaviors may change. You should use one of the support libraries when you need specific framework features that are newer than the minSdkVersion of your app or that are not available in the standard framework.

**What does support library actually do?**

There are many devices still running in Jelly bean and below versions. So you need to give the same importance for old and new devices While making an app. Otherwise, the App in old devices looks dull when compared to new ones. That may affect the app’s market. To avoid this trouble, Android introduced the Support library. These are set of code libraries provides backward compatibility

**Example:**

[Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) API was introduced in API 11 [HONEYCOMB](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0-highlights) .`android.app.Fragment` is the Fragment class introduced in API 11 and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` is the Fragment class in the android support library,

If you want to make your app use fragments, and want to **target devices before API 11**, you must use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. However, if you want only  **targeting devices >=API 11** ,you can use `android.app.Fragment`.Therefore, `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` is used to deliver newer features to older platforms.

For more info about android support library:[doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library)

Comment: Let me know if you have more query,Otherwise please accept answer of any person and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

1.Suppose you want to create an app which runs on platform comes after marshmallow.
then minimum sdk of your app will be marshmallow.

2.While creating your app you call a method which is present in oreo or later version then you app will have chances to crash on marshmallow and  nougat.